# Vega legend and color per mark

Tags: legend, vega

As you can see in the [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgFY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwogAw7FESCkbV8WgEx6DUQujVrGM6ltGKlkWCZnoANrC0A2koQoBBhUN6oyFoeXr4A+njc3D54jIQKwWGQsoFZ4cCQyFQyeP44kABUWPA+jPAA1gpQrIRq6HjRFcroAE4yABTteKyoAJSQAL75YAC6WdMQs26Gw5g4QQUzkJFdUHjo7D7R1uGQFL6syOVgm+FhhQAijLB4vfV4MQByyKyvdp95PtuAcfDEABwANmakHUWgAjOYgR4OElQTFIXoYQBNZB9GKWeEAdimp3uTxebw+31+-w0MLRvhiAGYAJzgmFwnDw5nI2CokFMirwrHI3H4iqEjmTMkFSDPV7veCfCo-P4HenIxlg4WiUSctQIgAsfIF6OFOhxeN6BJ08NZUxmy22b3QMlgADNuL1UHl7g8Zmc8ABPQh7SDwFLHZWZf1naS9FVgUJxs4exjIHyGirim2BsKLOOF8LzcKF53uBC+a5+gP+nboKIxXOx+6QENhmKEbiOQHbXpu6jh1QaRCts5qbgYRxaQprGIHI4nKDpzPZqAtvnepNvK7FsAyrIps67GL89ja8fZDvhuoya1XwwDpzh4ymPv1mT1Pa75CyqAAF7IL03BaL+-6QJO05yDgc4dOs+yHMcMKrlmZ5mky+6Hlsn6NuGkY+N6j77KG4beg43hghBz5DjE8AdDQ3rBsRkFTugM6wZB8ELkhy6QKh67ypSSqfFhSgVoY6AAB41hsR45O8yClDE7Agkkvp8vRyE5g+2EPApGbKRUxweoCUBVtp5kYWC5YrFAxxDjIag3HcITbOmPg6lABFERB3qGUmkDvO+LFKZGah7MebawMGqCqX4s5FKUwGJR5PgAPK2PAzDMZxFw+FcWg6HQoiTGVMxiUs1iQBgvQNC5R4uqRMTUCBrQsR6IG+rB+b8eg8DIEmUW4U2FSwMBGb+P+E7cRUi7IdN2StdwrTsLlUAKlSMb5vuEB6WctX1bW-rDW2N4xHeJz5oYnVTol85jRNNb7XGSXhZF13ZEpnQ2j1qb1lJiUWeGm4rhmaE6fiL3-VA62FMD6EXoKVFg2uiOXtD-0eG83ANJFHhafhKS+ajEMbcJ1KY6m2MgXjADq6iaHllx7PCu1Fp97N7Ytp1Bs1xmOFdMP8V192zeZT3+FTX0yO9s6fYY30pX9MPZIDnEI5DNrIgJza6Yt9ZwwT1bo8jKHg4JGMG9FON40DhN0cT2uk4Jm0iaSCvZIquPIAzo6JflhXclz9wh3tO1Ogs4kgNMQA), I want to create a chart with multiple marks. Each of these marks needs a specific color, a corresponding label and legend. I get that I define the color by "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "District"}. But I need a specific color for my 'subtotal' and 'totals' line. And the legend should read Neustadt - Totals and Neustadt - Subtotals.

I have played around with what I can find in the [scales](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/scales/#domain) documentation. But I just cant seem to make color and legend items by referenced marks field.

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"District": "Neustadt", "total": "86", "id": 12, "subtotal": "600", "Year": "2017"},
        {"District": "Neustadt", "total": "398", "id": 13, "subtotal": "100", "Year": "2018"},
        {"District": "Neustadt", "total": "155", "id": 14, "subtotal": "10", "Year": "2019"}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "collect",
          "sort": {
            "field": "Year"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "Year",
      "type": "point",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "Year", "sort": true}
    },
    {
      "name": "subtotal",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "subtotal"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "District"}
    }
  ]
```

I can only get one legend item or of course multiple items if I would have another district in the data. Is grouping marks an option?